# Is it possible to shutdown QuartzScheduler at Tomcat Context Stop?

Tags: tomcat, grails, quartz-scheduler

I have a Grails application that I want to shutdown Quartz when Tomcat stops the context.

I tried to use BootStrap destroy closure with no success, but I'm not sure if it's even possible through that route.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you need to set whether to wait for running jobs to complete on shutdown. Add to config:

```
quartz {
    waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown = false
}
```